# Getting python2.7 path in django app for subprocess call

Tags: linux, django, python-2.7, shell

I am using linux. I am trying to run daemon from function in django views. I want to run shell command from a view in Djangp app. I am using python 2.7. Command needs python2.7 path.

My app will be like plug n play. So on system on which it is going to install may have python installed on different location. So I want to make python path dynamic.

Command will be

```
    usr/bin/python2.7 filename.py --start
```

On my system path is usr/bin/python2.7.

I found follwing using os.

On python shell I tried following code & I get what I want

```
    import os
    getPyPath  = os.popen('which python2.7', 'r')
    pyPath = getPyPath.read()
    pyPath.rstrip()
```

I got o/p as which is expected as below

> usr/bin/python2.7

So now how to get this code is django app view function & run it so that I can get python path in a variable.

I found pythons subprocess module call using which we can run command through shell using shell=True.

So can I get above code running in django view function using subprocess call??

If not what is the other ways to get python path in variable in function django views.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is an odd requirement. In how many different systems do you intend to deploy this app? You could easily get off with a simple hard coded path.

Comment: Its a task for me to develop & submit. About where it will be installed I have no idea. Hard coded will not work there

Answer (score 1):

To view the full path to the current Python interpreter, use `sys.executable`

```
import sys

print(sys.executable)
```

Comment: Its showing '/usr/bin/python'. I want version specific path.

Comment: @Rohit this gives you "the full path to the current Python interpreter" as cleary Ian states. It shows you whichever python interpreter you are using.

Comment: I tried but its not working. I tried it on aws ec2 instance. There python2.7 installed somewhere in /opt/.../.... This is giving /usr/bin/python.

Comment: Does using virtualenv can affect this ??